# How to size images on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit

I'm making a spritekit game. I understand how to size my images in an SKScene because it's 750x1334 points across all devices, but the main page of the app uses UIKit/a collection view controller, so I'm not sure how to size my images. I want to have the images take up 1/3 of the screen width and then have the image height equal the image width.

> iPhone SE is 320x568 points
>
> iPhone 7 is 375x667 points
>
> iPad Pro 10.5 inch is 1112x834 points

Do I just make images that are 1/3 of the largest possible device width (1112 points) and then let smaller devices scale the images down? i.e.  1112 points divided by 3 is 370 points, so make images that are 370 points wide and high (740.6px@2x and 1112px@3x)?

Comment: did you use storyboard to add the image view? if yes then you can proportion while designing the image view by width or height

Comment: Perhaps, my question wasn't clear. I understand how to make the image 1/3 the size of the screen width. I don't know how many points and pixels to save my image as, so that it looks good on all screen sizes.

Comment: You may want to manually make your 1x 2x and 3x images

Comment: now in the 3 examples given, you may want to assign separate image assets and storyboads for your ipads and iphones, because all are @2x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have the images take up 1/3 of the screen width and then have the image height equal the image width. Do I just make images that are 1/3 of the largest possible device width (1112 points) and then let smaller devices scale the images down?

No. When you "let smaller devices scale the images down", you are still loading the full-sized image and thus wasting memory. Plus, letting the runtime scale the image down automatically (e.g. because you use an image view with an aspect fit or aspect fill content mode) wastes time and processing power, often at a critical moment when the app is trying to launch.

The correct procedure is:

- In your app *bundle*, you should include just *one* size for the image, possibly in three resolutions, and this should be the smallest size that is acceptable on the largest screen you'll be showing on.
- In your *code*, you should figure out the size at which the image will *actually* be displayed for the screen of the device we are running on, and load a thumbnail of the image sized down to that size.

In this way, no memory is wasted; the image held in memory is the image as displayed.

Answer (score 2):

In `Storyboard`, you can use the below steps,

1. Put equal width and equal height between image view and your actual view
2. Select the `equal width constraint` and change the multiplier from `1 to 1:3`
3. Select the `equal height constraint` and change the multiplier from `1 to 1:3`
4. The image view should occupy 1:3 of your screen size now.

Screenshots are attached for `iPhone` and `iPad` designs,

[image: image1] [image: image2][image: image3][image: image4]

Hope it helps.

Comment: No. Do not use image view sizing to size down a huge image. This wastes both time and memory. The right way is to load the image at its correct display size, at the time it is loaded.

Comment: @matt, this would not size down a huge image, the user can still add an image around the size of 1/3 of the screen and then let the storyboad scale it based on the varying difference across the devices

Comment: @matt  nevermind, you are talking more about using ipad graphics on iphone

Comment: Yes because that is what the question is about.